# Referencing fields in ACCESS DB in Visual Studio for WinForm App

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, ms-access

Newer to getting started with Visual Studio, but running into an issue i'm certain the pro's on here can answer.

I have an ACCESS DB data source connection to the Windows Form App I am building with Visual Basic programming in Visual Studio. For some reason when debugging, it is saying there is no amount of rows in the data, but clearly there is when you see the picture. I simply wanted to have a label update if a selection is made from a combo box based on a column and row entered on the data source.

How do I properly reference the Row 1, Column "BOM" from the Access DB in my line of code for the value to show up as "Dawn Page" for the label text? I get you have the 'datasource.datatable' precursor to the rest.

[image: VS Code on top and Source on Bottom]

Comment: Edit question to show attempted code.

Comment: The data won't just magically appear in your app. You have to retrieve it by querying the database. Have you done that? There's no indication here that you have.